# Problems installing PUPPETEER as a dependency - node.js on a VPS UBUNTU 20.04

Tags: node.js, error-handling, puppeteer, vps, ubuntu-20.04

I used npm install to install the dependencies of my project but it does not allow me to install puppeteer.

```
    npm ERR! command failed
    npm ERR! command sh -c node install.js
    npm ERR! ERROR: Failed to set up Chrome r115.0.5790.98! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD" env variable to    skip download.
    npm ERR! Error: Download failed: server returned code 403. URL:    https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/115.0.5790.98/linux64/chrome-linux64.zip
   npm ERR!     at /var/www/Backend/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/cjs/httpUtil.js:100:31
   npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.requestCallback (/var/www/Backend/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/cjs/httpUtil.js:77:13)
   npm ERR!     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
   npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
   npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (node:_http_client:701:27)
   npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:119:17)
   npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:542:22)
   npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
   npm ERR!     at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
   npm ERR!     at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-10-14T13_15_08_924Z-debug-0.log
```

I need to install puppeteer, I use it to generate pdfs and send them by email, the problem is that it does not allow me to install it so my project does not have said dependency. I don't know how to fix this error, I've been trying to solve it for a few days now.

Comment: 403 means they're blocking you for some reason. Maybe try a vpn or proxy